# VBA Syntax for copy data from once excel to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have two opened excels. I need to copy some particular column from excel 1 and paste it to excel 2. Can any one help me by providing the syntax to proceed further.

Comment: You'd do some googling before asking here. So, we'll help you in a better way after you shared some code snippets.

Comment: Do you mean inside one WorkBook from one WorkSheet to another?

Answer (score 0):

Try following for your needs:

```
Sub CopyColumns()
  Sheets("target").Columns("A").Value = Sheets("source").Columns("K").Value
  Sheets("target").Columns("B").Value = Sheets("source").Columns("U").Value
End Sub
```